# Area of a loop from a polar curve

Tags: solution-verification, area, polar-coordinates

Given the polar curve
$$r^2=9\cos(7\theta)$$
I have to evaluate the area of just one loop. What I thought was
$$9\cos(7\theta)=0\Leftrightarrow 7\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}\Rightarrow \theta=\frac{\pi}{14}$$
Then, the area of a loop would be
$$\int_{-\pi/14}^{\pi/14}\frac{r^{2}}{2}d\theta=\int_{-\pi/14}^{\pi/14}\frac{9\cos(7\theta)}{2}d\theta=\frac{9}{7}$$
I want to know if this is correct.

Comment: Yes it is correct.